# Visual studio code cleanup - autogenerated code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have some class generated by a tool, which adds section like this. It seems the *Analyze->Code cleanup* won't apply to this class.

```cs
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <auto-generated>
//    Generated by Xsd2Code++. Version 5.0.0.47. www.xsd2code.com
//    ...
//  </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is that some implicit behavior or is it somewhere configured?
Are there other ways to make the class ignored by the code *Analyze->Code cleanup* feature?

Comment: Do you mean to let the `Code cleanup` clean up such parts?

Comment: No, rather the opposite. My question originates from the fact that I am generating some code and need to DISABLE the code cleanup from doing changes there. I noticed this comment is often present in third-party generated code, and it seems to do the trick. I was just wondering what is the magic behind, and maybe what are the alternatives.

Comment: This! how to exclude a piece of code from the code cleanup. I have a piece with a specific indentation, which gets wrecked every time code cleanup/format is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on [code cleanup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2022#apply-code-styles).

For C# code files, Visual Studio 2019 has a Code Cleanup button at the bottom of the editor (keyboard: Ctrl+K, Ctrl+E) to apply code styles from an EditorConfig file or from the Code Style options page. If **an .editorconfig file** exists for the project, those are the settings that take precedence.

[image]

[image]

We can modify the code we don't want to clean up here. Just add and delete the corresponding rules.

Of course, you can also directly choose to close the code cleanup.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation link. If I understand it correctly, this is answer to how to add/remove the "fixers", however, I am trying to figure out how to exclude source code files, or rather which files are excluding by default.